# using VSE: how to disable the checkered section so you can view the strips?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I was working on one section of the video with on or two strips, trying masking blur and color, then when I tried to view the earlier sections, this is what I saw:

[image]

As you can see, the checkered earlier section should show other audio and video strips, but they are all gone. When I replay, I can hear audio, but I cannot see any video preview, except the lighter section which the playhead is at.

How do you disable the checkered section so you can see?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is the Lock Strip hotkey I accidentally was hitting (control H). All I had to do was Unlock (control alt H).